# Android Width of screen

Tags: android, button, width

I am trying to dynamically add buttons to an activity based on how wide a device's screen is. When I use `getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels` the returned value seems to be too large because buttons I attempt to draw at the edge are getting cut off. I tried getting the width of the layout but that returns 0. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with the padding, I didn't account for it. When I went into the XML and set the padding to 0, it fixed my problem.